# How to insert a "null" row without typing all column names?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

My objective is to insert a "null" row to my dimensions in a dataflow.

**Before**

| key | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | John | 20 |
| bbb | Doe | 33 |

**After**

| key | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | John | 20 |
| bbb | Doe | 33 |
| -1 | null | null |

I currently do this with:

```
Table.InsertRows(prevStep, 0, {[
  key = "-1",
  name = null,
  age = null
  ]}
)
```

**Question**

But can I somehow do the same operation, without having to type all the `null` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [key="aaa", name="John", age=20],
        [key="bbb", name="Doe", age=33]
    }),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
    {
        {"key", type text}, 
        {"name", type text}, 
        {"age", Int64.Type}
    }),
    #"Inserted Rows" = Table.InsertRows(#"Changed Type", 
        Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type"),  // insert at table end
        {
            Record.FromList(
                List.Combine({
                    {"-1"},
                    List.Repeat(
                        {null}, Table.ColumnCount(#"Changed Type") - 1)
                }),
                Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")
            )
        })
in
    #"Inserted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for showing me this. I'm now trying to implement the step, but I don't always know the position of the `key` column. Would it be possible for you to show me a piece of M, that would move the `key` column to always be in the start/end?

Comment: See: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2021/10/04/6289/resilient-relative-column-reordering. Works perfectly fine for your use case.